# Not able to iterate menu list through apex:repeat

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

```
<apex:component controller="MenuController">
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client">
        <apex:repeat value="{!menus}" var="menu" id="theRepeat">
             <apex:tab label="{!menu.name}" name="{!menu.id}">content for tab one</apex:tab>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:component>
```

Can any one please tell me what is wrong in this program? Why is this not creating a menus tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not supported.  The `apex:repeat` component cannot be used as a direct child of the following components according to the [apex:repeat docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm).

> This component cannot be used as a direct child of the following components:
>
> - <apex:dataTable>
> - <apex:pageBlockTable>
> - <apex:panelBar>
> - <apex:selectCheckboxes>
> - <apex:selectList>
> - <apex:selectRadio>
> - **<apex:tabPanel>**

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create your tab dynamically. I think the better way to do this is to use dynamic component. Check the SF-Docs out:

[Dynamic Visualforce Components](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/05/dynamic-visualforce-components-in-summer-11.html)

Comment: True.. but i just wanted to know why my code is not working

Comment: The <apex:tab> component **must be a child** of a <apex:tabPanel>. In your case it is NOT.

Comment: True ... but apex:repeat can be child of apex:tabPanel as written in docs.

Comment: Maybe a bug-feature von salesforce